# jQuery Slide Panel not working with PhoneGap

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have this code which works on browser, but when trying to run via PhoneGap compilation, the SCROLL FROM LEFT/SCROLL FROM RIGHT doesnt work, although I get the LEFT/RIGHT menus working when I click the button on top.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Open panel on swipe - jQuery Mobile Demos</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://d10ajoocuyu32n.cloudfront.net/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css">

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700">
    <script src="https://d10ajoocuyu32n.cloudfront.net/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d10ajoocuyu32n.cloudfront.net/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>



    <script>

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", alert("deviceready"),false);

     $(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
         $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
        });

        $( document ).on( "pageinit", "#demo-page", function() {

            $( document ).on( "swipeleft swiperight", "#demo-page", function( e ) {
                // We check if there is no open panel on the page because otherwise
                // a swipe to close the left panel would also open the right panel (and v.v.).
                // We do this by checking the data that the framework stores on the page element (panel: open).
                if ( $.mobile.activePage.jqmData( "panel" ) !== "open" ) {
                    if ( e.type === "swipeleft"  ) {
                        $( "#right-panel" ).panel( "open" );
                    } else if ( e.type === "swiperight" ) {
                        $( "#left-panel" ).panel( "open" );
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        /* Swipe works with mouse as well but often causes text selection. */
        #demo-page * {
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            -o-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
        }
        /* Arrow only buttons in the header. */
        #demo-page .ui-header .ui-btn {
            background: none;
            border: none;
            top: 9px;
        }
        #demo-page .ui-header .ui-btn-inner {
            border: none;
        }
        /* Content styling. */
        dl { font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif; padding: 1em; }
        dt { font-size: 2em; font-weight: bold; }
        dt span { font-size: .5em; color: #777; margin-left: .5em; }
        dd { font-size: 1.25em; margin: 1em 0 0; padding-bottom: 1em; border-bottom: 1px solid #eee; }
        .back-btn { float: right; margin: 0 2em 1em 0; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page" class="jqm-demos" id="demo-page">

    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
        <h1>Swipe left or right</h1>
        <a href="#left-panel" data-theme="d" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="notext" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="false" class="ui-icon-nodisc">Open left panel</a>
        <a href="#right-panel" data-theme="d" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="notext" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="false" class="ui-icon-nodisc">Open right panel</a>


    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content" >

        <dl>
            <dt>Swipe <span>verb</span></dt><br>
            <dt>Swipe <span>verb</span></dt><br>
            <dt>Swipe <span>verb</span></dt><br>
            <dt>Swipe <span>verb</span></dt><br>
            <dt>Swipe <span>verb</span></dt><br>
            <dt>Swipe <span>verb</span></dt><br>
            <dt>Swipe <span>verb</span></dt><br>
            <dt>Swipe <span>verb</span></dt><br>
            <dt>Swipe <span>verb</span></dt><br>
            <dt>Swipe <span>verb</span></dt><br>
            <dt>Swipe <span>verb</span></dt><br>
            <dt>Swipe <span>verb</span></dt><br>
            <dt>Swipe <span>verb</span></dt><br>
            <dt>Swipe <span>verb</span></dt><br>
            <dt>Swipe <span>verb</span></dt><br>
            <dt>Swipe <span>verb</span></dt><br>
            <dt>Swipe <span>verb</span></dt><br>
            <dt>Swipe <span>verb</span></dt><br>
            <dt>Swipe <span>verb</span></dt><br>
            <dt>Swipe <span>verb</span></dt><br>
            <dt>Swipe <span>verb</span></dt><br>
            <dt>Swipe <span>verb</span></dt><br>
            <dt>Swipe <span>verb</span></dt><br>
            <dt>Swipe <span>verb</span></dt><br>
            <dt>Swipe <span>verb</span></dt><br>
            <dt>Swipe <span>verb</span></dt><br>
            <dt>Swipe <span>verb</span></dt><br>
            <dt>Swipe <span>verb</span></dt><br>
            <dt>Swipe <span>verb</span></dt><br>
            <dt>Swipe <span>verb</span></dt><br>
            <dt>Swipe <span>verb</span></dt><br>
            <dt>Swipe <span>verb</span></dt><br>
            <dt>Swipe <span>verb</span></dt><br>
            <dt>Swipe <span>verb</span></dt><br>

            <dd><b>1.</b> to strike or move with a sweeping motion</dd>
        </dl>

        <a href="#demo-intro" data-rel="back" class="back-btn" data-role="button" data-mini="true" data-inline="true" data-icon="back" data-iconpos="right">Back to demo intro</a>


    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="panel" id="left-panel" data-theme="b" >

        <p>Left reveal panel.</p>

                <ul data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="b" data-inset="true">
                    <li data-role="list-divider" role="heading">
                        Menu
                    </li>
                    <li data-theme="c">
                        <a href="#" data-transition="slide">
                            Button
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li data-theme="c">
                        <a href="#page1" data-transition="slide">
                            Button
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li data-theme="c">
                        <a href="#page1" data-transition="slide">
                            Button
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li data-theme="c">
                        <a href="#page1" data-transition="slide">
                            Button
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li data-theme="c">
                        <a href="#page1" data-transition="slide">
                            Button
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
        <a href="#" data-rel="close" data-role="button" data-mini="true" data-inline="true" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="right">Close</a>

    </div><!-- /panel -->

    <div data-role="panel" id="right-panel" data-display="push" data-position="right" data-theme="b">

        <p>Right push panel.</p>
        <a href="#" data-rel="close" data-role="button" data-mini="true" data-inline="true" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="right">Close</a>

    </div><!-- /panel -->


    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
        <p class="jqm-version"></p>
        <p>Copyright 2013 InTouchMobile</p>
    </div><!-- /footer -->



</div><!-- /page -->




</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Also, tell me if there's any other way to get a FB/G+ Style slide menu, from BOTH THE SIDES !

Comment: am also facing the same problem .. never been able to resolve. Though never tried sencha touch.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the demo of slide panels on both sides DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/D9PQV/

## HTML

```
<div data-role="page" id="panel-fixed-page1">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>Fixed header</h1>
        <a href="#nav-panel" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext">Menu</a>
        <a href="#add-form" data-icon="gear" data-iconpos="notext">Add</a>
    </div><!-- /header -->
    <div data-role="content" class="jqm-content">
        <h1>Panels</h1>
        <h2>Fixed positioning</h2>
        <p>This is a typical page that has two buttons in the header bar that open panels. The left panel has the reveal display mode. The right panel opens as overlay. For both panels we set <code>data-position-fixed="true"</code>. We also set position fixed for the header and footer on this page.</p>
        <p>The left panel contains a long menu to demonstrate that the framework will check the panel contents height and unfixes the panel so its content can be scrolled. In the right panel there is a short form that shows the fixed positioning.</p>      
        <div data-demo-html="#panel-fixed-page1" data-demo-css="true"></div><!--/demo-html -->
    </div><!-- /content -->
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
        <h4>Fixed footer</h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
    
    <div data-role="panel" data-position-fixed="true" data-theme="a" id="nav-panel">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="a" class="nav-search">
            <li data-icon="delete"><a href="#" data-rel="close">Close menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Accordion</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">AJAX Navigation</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Autocomplete</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Buttons</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Checkboxes</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Collapsibles</a></li>                
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /panel -->

    <div data-role="panel" data-position="right" data-position-fixed="true" data-display="overlay" data-theme="b" id="add-form">
        <form class="userform">
            <h2>Login</h2>
            <label for="name">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" data-clear-btn="true" data-mini="true">
            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" data-clear-btn="true" autocomplete="off" data-mini="true">
            <div class="ui-grid-a">
                <div class="ui-block-a"><a href="#" data-rel="close" data-role="button" data-theme="c" data-mini="true">Cancel</a></div>
                <div class="ui-block-b"><a href="#" data-rel="close" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-mini="true">Save</a></div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div><!-- /panel -->
</div><!-- /page -->

<div data-role="page" id="panel-fixed-page2">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="f">
        <h1>Landing page</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->
    <div data-role="content" class="jqm-content">
        <p>This is just a landing page.</p>
        <a href="#panel-fixed-page1" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-mini="true" data-icon="back" data-iconpos="left">Back</a>
    </div><!-- /content -->
</div><!-- /page -->
```